# Could a powerful waterbender catch lightning by bending a circle of water?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

I have seen it in fanfiction somewhere and I think this should be possible. Of course, catching lightning is one thing, but safely disposing of it is quite another.

If the waterbender has to bend the water around themselves to create a full circle, then there is a danger of losing control and getting hurt. If, on the other hand, they could bend a circle in front of them, or even a vertical circle, then they could just jump away.

Was there any indication in canon (including the comics) that waterbender can
(a) create a sustained circles of water and
(b) redirect lightning?

Is there wasn’t, is it possible in the Avatar universe?

Comment: Are you suggesting that they *entirely* surround themselves with a sphere of water (creating a physical barrier) or that they surround themselves with a 2D circle of water, and that the lightning is somehow “attracted” to the water?

Comment: @Adamant, a 2D circle of water. If they create it on the path of the lightning, then it should travel around the circe like an electric curcuit, I think. The sphere should work too, but this would require a lot more power

Comment: Relevant for the other discussion is whether it could happen IRL: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1mm794/when_lightning_hits_a_large_body_of_water_how_far/

Comment: Lightningbending couldn't work IRL because the lighning would take the least resistant way to the ground. It would only work at really close quarters otherwise it would go straight form the Hand to the ground. So I don't think that it is relevant for the discussion whether it could happen IRL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for a)
Circles of Water have been used [image]

As for b)
In Katara's fight against Azula she tried to block a Lightning. The Water instantly evaporated. Even though it seemed to block the lightning I don't think it would be a very effective way do defend against lightning. At least it isn't redirecting it.
[image]